# Complemented $\ell_q$ subspaces of $(\oplus_n\ell_p^n)_\infty$

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, lp-spaces

Fix $1\leq p<\infty$, and denote
\begin{equation*}(\oplus_n\ell_p^n)_\infty=\left\{\left((a_i^{(n)})_{i=1}^n\right)_{n=1}^\infty:\left(\|(a_i^{(n)})_{i=1}^n\|_p\right)_{n=1}^\infty\in\ell_\infty\right\}\end{equation*}
i.e. the $\ell_\infty$-sum of $\ell_p^n$'s, endowed with the obvious norm.  Furthermore, if $X$ is a Banach space then we denote by $\ell_\infty(X)$ the $\ell_\infty$-sum of infinitely many copies of $X$.

**Question.**  For which values $q\in[1,\infty]$ is $\ell_q$ isomorphic to a complemented subspace of $(\oplus_n\ell_p^n)_\infty$?

Let me summarize what I know so far.  Clearly, $q=\infty$ works.  Taking $q=p$ also works, as is mentioned in Remark 3.4 of the paper "On the mutually non isomorphic $\ell_p(\ell_q)$ spaces" by Cembranos/Mendoza.

One might conjecture that these are the only $q$'s that work, but actually whenever $p\in(1,\infty)$ we also get $\ell_2$ complemented.  Here's how.

**Theorem 1.**  $(\oplus_n\ell_p^n)_\infty$ is isomorphic to $\ell_\infty(\ell_p)$.

This is just from Remark 3.4 in Cembranos/Mendoza.  Let us give some more info from that paper.

**Corollary 1.**  The space $\ell_q$, $q\in[1,\infty]$, is isomorphic to a complemented subspace of $(\oplus_n\ell_1^n)_\infty$ if and only if $q=1$ or $q=\infty$.

(See Prop. 6.1.)  On the other hand, Cembranos/Mendoza showed in Proposition 3.5 that $\ell_2$ is complemented in $\ell_\infty(\ell_p)$ whenever $1<p<\infty$.  Hence:

**Corollary 2.**  The space $\ell_2$ is isomorphic to a complemented subspace of $(\oplus_n\ell_p^n)_\infty$ if and only if $1<p<\infty$.

Using Theorem 1 above to replace "$\ell_\infty(\ell_p)$" with "$(\oplus_n\ell_p^n)_\infty$" in Proposition 4.3 of Cembranos/Mendoza, we also have the following.

**Corollary 3.**  If the space $\ell_q$, $q\in(1,\infty)$, is isomorphic to a complemented subspace of $(\oplus_n\ell_p^n)_\infty$, $p\in(1,\infty)$, then either $1<p\leq q\leq 2$ or $2\leq q\leq p<\infty$.

Comment: so  $Y = l_\infty(l^p) = (\oplus_n l_p)_\infty$. $\ \ $what is the completion of $X = (\oplus_n l_p^n)_\infty$ ? (where $l_p^n$ means $\mathbb{R}^n,\|.\| _p$, not $n$ copies of $l_p$ ?)

Comment: you have to explain how $l_2$ can be isomorphic to a subspace of the completion of $\oplus_n l_p^n$ (and what is $\oplus_n l_p^n$ and its completion)

Comment: @user1952009 I'm not sure I understand your comments. The space $(\oplus_n\ell_p^n)_\infty$ is defined above, the $\ell_\infty$-sum of $\ell_p^n$'s. It is already a Banach space and so requires no completion to make it one. That $\ell_2$ is isomorphic to a subspace (when $1<p<\infty$) follows from my Theorem 1 above together with Proposition 3.5 from the Cembranos/Mendoza paper.

Comment: what is $l_p^n$ ? (and the $l^2$ theorem is the only interesting one, so you have to explain it in simple words)

Comment: @user1952009 $\ell_p^n$ is the space $(\mathbb{R}^n,\|\cdot\|_p)$, or possibly $(\mathbb{C}^n,\|\cdot\|_p)$ if we are looking at complex Banach spaces.

Comment: Then why the completion of $X = (\oplus_n l_p^n)_\infty$ isn't $(\oplus_n l_p^n)_\infty \oplus l_p \oplus l_\infty$ ?  (using that $\oplus_n l_\infty = l_\infty$)

Comment: @user1952009 I believe $X$ is isomorphic to $X\oplus\ell_p\oplus\ell_\infty$, yes, but I'm not sure how that's helpful.

Comment: then no $l_2$ here (when $p \ne 2$)

Comment: @user1952009 Why not?  Just because $X\approx X\oplus\ell_p\oplus\ell_\infty$ doesn't mean that $\ell_2$ is not complemented in $X$.  For instance, just take $X=\ell_2\oplus\ell_p\oplus\ell_\infty$.

Comment: we said that $\overline{X} = X \oplus l_p \oplus l_\infty$, and it doesn't contain $l_2$ (when $p \ne 2$).  (or I'm missing something mysterious that you have to explain)

Comment: Though I don't know how complemented subspaces of $\ell_\infty(\ell_p)$ look like, it is known that the space in questio is primary (http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022247X06002903)

Comment: @Norbert thank you! Interesting stuff